# How to dynmically get the Python enum class in a sqlalchemy Enum column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, enums

I have a model with an Enum column that uses a python Enum class

```py
import enum
import sqlalchemy

# ...

class MyCoolEnum(str, enum.Enum):
  A = "A"
  B = "B"
  C = "C"

class MyModel(Base):
  __tablename__ = "mymodel"

  cool_enum_val = Column(Enum(MyCoolEnum))
```

I need to get the class of the enum in runtime, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the class by accessing `enum_class` on the column's type, like so:

```py
print(MyModel.cool_enum_val.type.enum_class)
# <enum 'MyCoolEnum'>
```

Alternatively, you can access the column dynamically with:

```py
print(MyModel.__table__.columns['cool_enum_val'].type.enum_class)
# <enum 'MyCoolEnum'>
```

Comment: Since you are answering your own question, it makes sense to also accept the answer, to mark that it is answered adequately. Unless you disagree with it ;)

Comment: @zvone: good reminder about accepting the answer, but the system does make the OP wait 24 hours before doing so.

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to accept the answer immediately but couldn't and then just forgot :)